# postgres store hash string: invalid message format

Tags: postgresql, libsodium

In my node.js application I should be able to create some new users.
And to store the passwords in a secure fashion, I use the sodium-native library to generate argon2 hashes (https://github.com/sodium-friends/sodium-native). Now I try to store a string representation of those hashes in my postgres database.

The JavaScript query string looks like this:

`INSERT INTO users (email, name, password) VALUES ('${email}', '${name}', '${pwHash}')`

And the generated sql statement looks as follows:

`INSERT INTO users (email, name, password) 
VALUES ('test@test.org', 'test', '$argon2id$v=19$m=8,t=1,p=1$WAw+HmO/+RZTazVr3eOnPg$HYzaB0+Cre23XGR+A1cZawrUvkon2Cx3x7ua5I68xGo                                   ')`

Besides the hash, there is some further information stored about it to help verify passwords.
I don't know why it produces all those white-spaces, but I think it is due to the fixed length of the buffer used.

My problem is that postgres, for some reason, sends me an error: `invalid message format, code: '08P01'`Now, that code means `protocol violation`, whatever that means.
The funny thing is: when I just hard code the hash as it appears in my browser or console, then it works:

`INSERT INTO users (email, name, password) 
VALUES ('${email}', '${name}', '$argon2id$v=19$m=8,t=1,p=1$WAw+HmO/+RZTazVr3eOnPg$HYzaB0+Cre23XGR+A1cZawrUvkon2Cx3x7ua5I68xGo                                   ')`
It doesn't seem to make a difference, if I remove the white-spaces or not.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Edit: I was asked if those "blanks" really are white-spaces. At least I think so, because they appear as ones in the editor and browser and copy as ones as well. I tried to manually remove them and it didn't make any difference.
I also tried to use string concatenation instead of interpolation, but it also didn't make any difference.

Comment: What happens if you use placeholders rather than string interpolation? Are you sure those "spaces" are spaces rather than something else that looks like spaces?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by placeholders? As far as I know, there is no equivalent to sprintf in JavaScript. As for the white-spaces: At least in the text editor and in the browser, they appear as white-spaces and are copied as those as well. I am not sure though how I could further confirm this.

Comment: Whatever you're using to connect to PostgreSQL should be able to handle SQL like `"insert into users (email, name, password) values (?, ?, ?)"` or `"insert into users (email, name, password) values ($1, $2, $3)"` and then values are supplied for the `?` or `$n` placeholders. Using string interpolation for building SQL is irresponsible at best. You could try putting the `pwHash` string through a hex-dumper or examining it byte by byte to see what's really in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of converting the buffer to a string first, I now store the hash as raw binary data (data-type bytea) as it is generated by sodium-native. That also makes password verification trivial. Please do follow mu is too short's advise about SQL injection.